# Broadcasting in CVXPY

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy

I'm trying to train a linear model with bias using CVXPY. Suppose `input` and `target` are given. Suppose `loss` is a cvxpy function, convex in its 1st argument. I have the following code:

```
import cvxpy as cvx
n_data = 100
d_in = 10
d_out = 10
beta = cvx.Variable(d_in, d_out)
bias = cvx.Variable(d_out)

input = np.random.rand(n_data, d_in)
...
objective = cvx.Minimize(loss(input @ beta + bias, target))
problem = cvx.Problem(objective)

problem.solve()
```

I get a broadcasting error due to `input @ beta + bias` :  Cannot broadcast dimensions  (100, 10) (10,)

Comment: You can write ``bias[None, :]`` and it will broadcast. Broadcasting along defined dimensions is supported, just not broadcasting along undefined dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the outer product of `bias` with the vector of ones and defining `bias = cvx.Variable((d_out, 1))` does the trick. Use:

```
input @ beta + np.ones((n_data, 1)) @ bias
```